# create array of arrays from one array of Series(in c++)

Tags: c++

how i create an array of arrays, from One-dimensional array of Series, example:
I have an array like :

```
long int arr[20] = {23, 91, -71, -63, 22,  55, 51, 73, 17, -19,-65, 44, 95,  66, 82, 85, 97, 30, 54, -34};
```

and i want to create array of arrays in ascending order like: (in c++)

```
23, 91  
-71, -63, 22,  55  
51, 73  
17  
-19  
-65, 44, 95  
66, 82, 85, 97  
30, 54  
-34
```

already tried to now how many array there are

```
int sum=0;
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    if(arr[i]>arr[i+1])sum++;
return sum;
```

Comment: your question isn't clear. Where did you try to make array of arrays in your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum=0;
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    if(arr[i]>arr[i+1])sum++;
return sum;
```

should be

```
int sum = 0;
if (n > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        if (arr[i] > arr[i+1])
            sum++;
    sum++;
}
```

Your version doesn't count the last sequence of ascending numbers.

That's a start, what you have to do next is allocate enough memory for a pointer to each row. Then you go through the numbers again, count the length of each row, allocate the memory for that row, and then go through that row again, copying the numbers for that row. It's just loops (inside loops). Have a go and post the code if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating `vector of vector` instead of `array of array`? In array you have to determine size which will cause you, either `index out of bound exception` or huge `space lost`. If you use vector, you are not going to determine size of vector, it will allocate more space as you fill the size of vector.

If your initial array is descending order, your double array size will be `nx1`, if it is ascending order, then `1xn` so you have to make your double array `nxn` not to give `exception` which is inacceptible when `n > 10^4` (approximately).

Some basic syntax of `vector of vector` is as follows:

```
vector<vector<int>> myvect; //initialization
myvect.at(i).at(j) = x;     //reaching i_th row, j_th col element
myvect.at(0).push_back(1);  //add element to the end of the row0.
```

This [website](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/33631-c-vector-tutorial/) looks nice about explaining vectors.

Here is sample code, I didn't test it so there might be small syntax erra,

```
vector<vector<int>> myvect; //initialization

int size = 20;
long int arr[size] = {23, 91, -71, -63, 22,  55, 51, 73, 17, -19,-65, 44, 95,  66, 82, 85, 97, 30, 54, -34};

int row = -1; int val = arr[0]+1;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    if(arr[i] < val){
        row++;
        myvect.push_back(vector<int> () );
    }
    myvect.at(row).push_back(arr[i]);
}
```

The code is basically like this.

Comment: 'I'm not sure about the syntax', it's `myvect.push_back(vector<int>());`. Your code does have a couple of logic errors too.

Comment: _"I'm not sure about the syntax"_ . This is not an algorithm tagged question, don't write pseudo codes. If you don't know syntax, why don't you just explain the logic

Comment: @john what is that logic error? Is it related to first row? Thanks for correction by the way.

Comment: @smttsp Yes the first row, I think you've fixed them since I wrote that. BTW you can use `myvect.back().push_back(arr[i]);`, `back` returns a reference to the last item in a vector. Saves you having to use the `row` variable.

Comment: Thanx, but i can't use vector of vectors, i have to use array of arrays (not a matrix), like long int**arr;

Answer (score -1):

You could do

```
array[9][4] = {
            { 23, 91 },  
            { -71, -63, 22,  55  },
            { 51, 73  },
            { 17  },
            { -19  },
            { -65, 44, 95  },
            { 66, 82, 85, 97  },
            { 30, 54  }
            { -34 }
          };
```

Comment: Ho, ho, but unhelpful and not legal C++ (`array[][]` is incorrect).

Comment: @john Ah, didn't know. I eddited it.